# Initializer list failing for templated code in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, c++14

The code:

```
class FString : public StringFormatter<FString> {
public:
    FString()
        : StringFormatter<FString>{this->buffer}
        {}

    // allow assignment and construction from std::string.

    FString(const std::string &other)
        :
        StringFormatter<FString>{this->buffer},
        buffer{other} {}
```

gives a syntax error at

```
StringFormatter<FString>{this->buffer}
```

Converting it to

```
StringFormatter<FString>(this->buffer) works.
```

Errors:

```
../util/stringformatter.h(250): error C2059: syntax error: '{' ../util/stringformatter.h(250): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
../util/stringformatter.h(256): error C2059: syntax error: ','
../util/stringformatter.h(257): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
```

Here is the concerned file: https://github.com/synth2014/openage/blob/master/libopenage/util/stringformatter.h#L250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in MSVC.

You can either use a typedef/alias:

```
using base = StringFormatter<FString>;
FString() : base{this->buffer} {}
```

or part with the braced-init-list:

```
FString() : StringFormatter<FString>(this->buffer) {}
```

to work around the issue.

Comment: I've filed a bug on connect [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2386351/c-syntax-error-for-brace-init-list-of-base-class-template), I'll update my answer when there's a response.

Comment: The Visual C++ team responded; the bug should be fixed with VS2015 Update 3 :)

Comment: I checked with VS 2015 update 3 today and it seems to be fixed.